# Proxmox bridged TAP-to-TAP virtio performance slow

Tags: performance, bridge, proxmox

so a little info about my setup:

- Running Proxmox 5.3-11 with latest updates
- Running 2 Windows 2012 guests (we'll call them `winhost1` and `winhost2`) with `virtio` NICs and latest [spice-guest-tools](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html) (with the `netsh` modifications described [here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/kvmnet/registry))

I'm using `iperf` between the 2 Windows guests to gauge the bandwidth between them. Going from either `winhost1` to `winhost2`, and vice versa, I see a maximum bandwidth rate of ~350Mpbs. However, when I `iperf` from either `winhost1` or `winhost2` to the Proxmox host, I receive a +2Gbps bandwidth rate. Going the other direction in either case yields similar results.

The bridge slaving the `winhost1` and `winhost2` virtual NICs (`vmbr0`) was created within the Proxmox GUI with a `balance-alb` bond as the "Bridge port". Below is the output of `bridge link show vmbr0`:

```
9: bond1 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master vmbr0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
26: tap106i1 state UNKNOWN : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master vmbr0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
27: tap102i1 state UNKNOWN : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master vmbr0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100
```

Is there anything I can do on either the host or the VMs to address this issue? I assume this is related to the host kernel config in some way since I see the desired bandwidth rates between the VMs and the host, just not between the VMs attached to the host bridge.

Thank you in advance